# Port monitor for Win7 x64, to help debug my app which communicates with a socket server?

Tags: sockets

I'm developing C# software to talk to a 3rd party socket based server, "socketServer.exe".

There is an existing demo program that I can run which will let me do basic things, such as connect to "socketServer.exe" on localhost, port 5009, and grab some data.

What utility do you recommend to:

- 1) find out what ports "socketServer.exe" is using to communicate to the demo app;
- 2) monitor traffic on port 5009 between my app ("myapp.exe") and socket 5009, both on localhost.

Comment: p.s. I tried WireShark - but unfortunately, this didn't work as it only seems to monitor traffic that actually passes through the Ethernet interface. As both programs ("myapp.exe" + "socketServer.exe") are running on the same computer, it doesn't seem to pick anything up, probably because everything is on localhost, bypassing the Ethernet interface (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nettool @ http://nettool.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps.
Johan

Comment: Thanks, this utility definitely has its place.